# C# Автокомплит из базы нескольких значений

Tags: c#

Хочу подставлять названия, подтягивая их из базы

```
    private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        if (t != null)
        {
            //say you want to do a search when user types 3 or more chars
            if (t.Text.Length >= 3)
            {
          var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(txb);
                    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                    string name = null;
                    foreach (var element in results)
                    {
                        name = (string)element.name;
                        source.Add(name);
                    }

                    textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
```

таким образом сразу подставляется значение, а не несколько.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы при каждом изменении textBox'а заново парсите json. Вам не кажется, что это накладно? Распарсите его один раз и запомните (создайте отдельное поле).

Далее, по проблеме с подстановкой. Скорее всего, выставлен мод `SuggestAppend`. А он в связке с динамическим изменением `AutoCompleteCustomSource` у textBox'а из-за своего механизма дает вот такую проблему.
Если не нужно, чтобы в самом textBox'е дописывалось слово, а нужен только список, можно изменить мод на `Suggest`. Если такое поведение не подходит, то в Вашем случае `AutoCompleteCustomSource` можно менять всего лишь один раз: тогда, когда текст textBox'а стал больше 3-ех символов. Можно попробовать следующий способ:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = EmptyAutoCompleteCustomSource;
}

private AutoCompleteStringCollection EmptyAutoCompleteCustomSource { get; set; } = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
private AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoCompleteCustomSource { get; set; }

private AutoCompleteStringCollection CreateAutoCompleteCustomSource() {
    AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(txb);
    foreach(var element in results)
        source.Add((string)element.name);

    return source;
}

private void UpdateAutoCompleteCustomSource() => AutoCompleteCustomSource = CreateAutoCompleteCustomSource();

private void EnsureAutoCompleteCustomSource() {
    if(AutoCompleteCustomSource == null)
        UpdateAutoCompleteCustomSource();
}

private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    if(t != null) {
        // Проверки на textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource нужны, чтобы изменение AutoCompleteCustomSource
        // было один раз при выполнении данного условия
        if(t.Text.Length >= 3 && textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource == EmptyAutoCompleteCustomSource) {
            EnsureAutoCompleteCustomSource();
            textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoCompleteCustomSource;
        } 
        else if(t.Text.Length < 3 && textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource == AutoCompleteCustomSource)
            textBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = EmptyAutoCompleteCustomSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: так сразу получать список из 500 значений не очень хорошо. как быть чтобы список обновлялся после ввода 3 букв по like?

Comment: @des1roer В вашем примере список из 500 элементов тянулся каждый раз при изменении textbox'а, что как раз не есть хорошо. И 500 элементов - это не так много.

Comment: @des1roer если все же 500 элементов много для Вас, а каждый раз обращаться к файловой системе/бд  - норма, то менять AutoCompleteCustomSource нужно через небольшую задержку, когда отработает механизм AutoComplete. Сделать можно это через таймер. Если мод просто Suggest, то можно обойтись без задержек и сразу менять.

Comment: но он тянется по условию like '3 elem'

Comment: @des1roer , но тянутся 500 элементов. Если, конечно, продакшен код такой же, как и в примере. У Вас получается: ввели 2 символа - ничего не произошло, ввели 3 символа - загрузили 500 записей; ввели 4 символа - загрузили те же 500 записей, 5 символа - опять те же 500 записей, и т.д. У меня: один раз загрузил в самом начале. Могу чуть позже переделать, чтобы обращение к моему свойству AutoCompleteCustomSource было лениво, т.е. загрузка записей будет один раз и когда первый раз введённых символов будет больше 3. Буду с компьютера, отредактирую ответ.

Comment: @des1roer, обновил ответ.